# Family member received iMessage suggesting a connection/phone breach. What is really happening here?

Tags: iphone, instant-messaging

This family member is an iPhone user. I am an Android user. The messages look normal until a short while ago, when it appears the connection was switched to iMessage. They immediately used another messaging app to send me a screenshot and suggest my phone might be compromised ("hacked").

The conversation in question is below:

[image: iPhone Conversation]

The hijacked conversation occurs during the lesson mentioned, and I assume they are not connected to any public WiFi.

Whose phone or connection is likely compromised here, and what could be happening to cause a breach like this?

Further to the comment below, if my number was used to create an Apple ID, how was this possible when this number has been in use for more than a decade?

Comment: It doesn't sound like your phone was compromised, just that somebody created an appleid with your phone number.

Comment: @nobody Thanks for the reply! Wouldn't that mean someone successfully spoofed my number? This phone number has been in use by me for more than 10 years.